# "issuing_ca" in Hachicorp Vault

Tags: ssl, hashicorp-vault, ca

I am trying to understand the steps in [this](https://learn.hashicorp.com/tutorials/vault/pki-engine) tutorial for creating CA with Vault. When creating a certificate, we get "certificate" and "issuing_ca" [example](https://www.vaultproject.io/api/secret/pki#sample-response-8), and I can't figure out what whould be the equivalent for this "issuing_ca" in `openssl` terminology or how it's being generated.

Any ideas?

Comment: https://www.omnisecu.com/security/public-key-infrastructure/certificate-authority-ca-hierarchy.php